# Set static IP on jetson nano

Tags: networking, nvidia, ethernet

I need to set static IP address on Jetson nano. I have edited /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.192
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.1.255
```

Currently eth0 is disabled:

```
#cat /run/network/ifstate
lo=lo
```

But it fails to go up:

```
#ifup eth0
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to setup my static IP address. You were close, but you must have a valid gateway. "255" is the broadcast address, not the gateway...

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.192
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 192.168.1.0
  broadcast 192.168.1.255
  gateway 192.168.1.1
  dns-nameservers 75.75.75.75 75.75.76.76
  dns-search m2osw.com
```

Make sure to use valid `dns-nameservers` and for the `dns-search`, you probably don't need that line. If you don't want to access the Internet from the Jetson, then you also don't need the `dns-nameservers`.